# Automapper Upgrade FindTypeMapFor<>

Tags: c#, automapper

I'm updating an old .NET Framework application to the latest supported Automapper nuget (from v3.3.1 to v10.0.0).   The original code extends automapper in horrendous ways, which I have been able to convert to use built in methods, except this one:

```
// Ignores all destination properties which would otherwise be mapped by convention.
public static IMappingExpression<TSource, TDestination> IgnoreUnMapped<TSource, TDestination>(this IMappingExpression<TSource, TDestination> expression)
{
    TypeMap map = Mapper.FindTypeMapFor<TSource, TDestination>();

        foreach (var property in map.GetCustomPropertyMaps()
          .Where(p => p.CustomExpression == null)
          .Select(p => p.DestinationProperty.Name))
    {
        expression.ForMember(property, opt => opt.Ignore());
    }
    return expression;
}
```

I found [this page](https://davecallan.com/automapper-4-2-ignoreallnonexisting-ignore-missing-properties/) , that gives a workaround for v4.2, but that no longer works for v10.

Comment: You could get `TypeMap` with `var map = _mapper.ConfigurationProvider.Internal().FindTypeMapFor<TDest, TSource>();`

Comment: Remove it and use `ConvertUsing` instead. Simpler, faster, easier to understand.

Comment: @AlexKovanev _mapper is not available during configuration.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu How would ConvertUsing help?  I want to /not/ convert a subset of properties.

Comment: You replace _all_ the configuration for that map with `ConvertUsing`.

Comment: I have literally hundreds of classes that use this method.  Changing them all would take too long.

Comment: Surely it's needed only in a few places. Otherwise I don't see the point of using AM. Ignoring hundreds of auto matched properties. That's absurd :)

Comment: Totally absurd, i agree, but that's the codebase I'm working on.

Comment: In AM 10 you can use `ForAllOtherMembers(o=>o.Ignore())`.

Comment: It's subtle, but that's not the answer. Your suggestio will ignore everything not already mapped, whereas I want unmapped convention based mapping to continue, but unmapped complex (custom) mapping to be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

This requires a cast, but this is the only option that Automapper authors left for people that actually have to maintain software:

```
    var typeMapConfiguration = (TypeMapConfiguration)expression;

    foreach (var property in typeMapConfiguration.TypeMap.GetUnmappedPropertyNames())
    {
        expression.ForMember(property, opt => opt.Ignore());
    }
```